# Rails upgrade undefined method `cookie_verifier_secret`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, upgrade

Was getting deprecation warning message in the last version.

Now I can't run the server at all, I'm getting 
`config/initializers/cookie_verification_secret.rb:7:in <top (required)>': undefined method cookie_verifier_secret=' for ActionController::Base:Class (NoMethodError)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The fix was to change:

```
config/initializers/cookie_verification_secret.rb
```

Changing:

```
ActionController::Base.cookie_verifier_secret=
```

to

```
ActionController::Base.config.secret_token=
```